# Deleting a label that was duplicated

Tags: c#, label

I have a program where a user fills in a form and hits calculate, then when the user hits summary it will show all the users that have entered in data. When more users enter data, they are simply added to the summary using the same lbl (lblUsers) the only problem I am having is being able to delete the most recent entry into the summary which would be the newest made label.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace LifeInsurance
{
public partial class frmMain : Form
{
    double commissionRate;
    double insuranceAmount;
    double totalAmount;
    int numberOfCustomers;
    double totalInsuranceDollars;
    double totalCommission;



    private void btnClearAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblUsers.Text = "";
    }

    public frmMain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }





    private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string firstName = txtFirstName.Text;
            string lastName = txtLastName.Text;
            insuranceAmount = int.Parse(txtInsuranceAmount.Text);
        }catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You must enter all details");
        }
        if(insuranceAmount>= 1000)
        {
            commissionRate = 0.005;
            totalAmount = insuranceAmount * 0.005;
        }
        if (insuranceAmount >= 100000)
        {
            commissionRate = 0.0010;
            totalAmount = insuranceAmount * 0.0010;
        }
        if (insuranceAmount >= 1000000)
        {
            commissionRate = 0.0015;
            totalAmount = insuranceAmount * 0.0015;
        }
        totalInsuranceDollars += totalAmount;
        totalCommission += commissionRate;
        numberOfCustomers += 1;
        lblUsers.Text += "Name: "+txtFirstName.Text +" "+ txtLastName.Text+"         
        "+ "Payout Amount: "+totalAmount+Environment.NewLine;
        lblUsers.Text += "Total Policies: " + numberOfCustomers+" " + "Total 
        Insurance Dollars Earned: " + totalInsuranceDollars+" " + "Total 
        Commission Earned: " + totalCommission+Environment.NewLine;
    }
    private void btnSummary_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblUsers.Visible = true ;
    }
    private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //remove one label
    }

  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you post example of what the label looks like?  Or at least what its text looks like after a few entries?

Comment: @MAW74656 added an image of a sample output, want to delete the last label that starts at Name

Comment: Its going to be really difficult to find and delete what you want like this.  I would suggest a couple of different approaches.  1) Use a textarea and instead of deleting, let older items scroll off the screen.  2) Add new labels to a panel each time, then you can loop through the labels and delete one which contains your search terms.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, if I understand correctly you want your Label to show all but the last entry when the user clicks "Summary" is that correct? So in your screenshot it shows 3 entries, but you want only 2 entries to be shown?

If so, see if this helps:

```
public static void btnSummary_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string currentText = lblUsers.Text;
        int positionOfLastEntry = currentText.LastIndexOf("Name:");
        string textWithoutLastEntry = currentText.Substring(0, positionOfLastEntry);
        lblUsers.Text = textWithoutLastEntry;
        lblUsers.Visible = true;
    }
```